# How to combine Boolean and Fuzzy logic?

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, overlay, fuzzy-logic

So I have a set of 5 Fuzzy Memberships and a polygon feature class, to which I already added a yes/no field. For the final map, I need to combine/overlay all Fuzzy Memberships and the rasterized polygon feature class in order to map suitability, and don't know how to combine it.
Any advice?

Comment: Could you please supply more details about your problem?  Are you looking for a tutorial on fuzzy overlay?  Thanks...

Comment: I need to create a map to satisfy various conditions. For almost all conditions I have used the Fuzzy Membership, except for one which is a polygon feature class outlining sensitive areas. I am just stuck on how to combine the rasterized layer with the fuzzy memberships.

Comment: Sorry @Geog, link is not working for me :(

Comment: Here's the link he posted -- http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0410/files/fuzzylogic.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the link. Everything seems pretty clear, but I still don't  know whether I can combine the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two main logical operators : the AND and the OR.

In fuzzy logic, you can use:

"fuzzy AND" as an equivalent of the minimum of the different membership values

"fuzzy OR" as an equivalent of the maximum of the different membership values

if you want to combine this with your crisp decision, you can convert "yes" to 1 and "no" to 0. Then you can simply multiply the combined set of fuzzy membership by these values.